# I want to xpath navigate to a node, then move to sibling mode, create a nodelist to write the contents to a listbox

Tags: xml, xpath

I am very new to VB, and more so with XML and xpath. I have a listview box that passes a variable needed to identify a node in an xml file (in the case below the variable is the text value of id element.

The variable selects a node, but I need the innertext of some of its sibling/child nodes.
I know how to make xmlnodelists and write the innertext of them no problem, but I cannot make this work. here is a sample of my xml (I didn't write the xml file and therefore can't change it):

```
<file>
  <outcomes>
   <outcome>
    <id>CPK</id>
    <id_text>description</outcome_text>
    <indicators>
        <indicator>
            <p>the text i want to write to listbox</p>
        </indicator>
        <indicator>
            <p>more text I want to write</p>
        </indicator>
    </indicators>
   </outcome>
  <outcome>
  <outcome>
    <id>CPK</id>
    <id_text>description</id_text>
    <indicators>
        <indicator>
            <p>the text i want to write to listbox</p>
        </indicator>
        <indicator>
            <p>more text I want to write</p>
        </indicator>
    </indicators>
   </outcome>
  <outcome>
 </outcomes>    
</file>
```

so let's say the variable passed is "CPK"

here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'get variable to identify node
    Dim id As String
    Dim out As String
    id = Me.outListView.SelectedItems(0).Text
    out = Me.outListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    IndForm.SelOutBox.Text = id & "  " & out

    'start xpath navigation
    Dim document As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument("C:\Temp\" & sb & "_education_" & gr & ".XML")
    Dim navigator As XPathNavigator = document.CreateNavigator()


    'select the node with with variable, by text value
    navigator.SelectSingleNode("/files/outcomes/goal_section/outcome/id[@text='" & id & "']")

    'move to the needed node
    navigator.MoveToNext() 'should be at /outcome/id_text
    navigator.MoveToNext() 'should be at /outcome/indicators
    navigator.MoveToFirstChild() 'should be at /outcome/indicators/indicator
    navigator.MoveToFirstChild() 'should be at /outcome/indicators/indicator/p

    'now what? I want to loop through the <p> elements and have some sort of do statement and write them to 
    'to the IndForm.Listbox1

    IndForm.Show()
End Sub
```

The real file has many "p" elements for each ID. Any help (I am sure there is a much easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the values of the `p`s that match the ID you have (I'll use semi-pseudocode since I don't know VB syntax that well):

```
 Dim pNodes as XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select(
                 "/files/outcomes/outcome[id = '" & id & 
                 "']/indicators/indicator/p")

 While pNodes.MoveNext
    ' pNodes.Current.Value is the current value
 Loop
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Correct me if I am wrong, but that select path is looking for the ID value in the outcome element. It is in the ID element, which is a sibling of the ID. It tried this, but no luck: 
        `code Dim pNodes As XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select("/curriculum/outcomes/goal_section/outcome[id = '" & id & "']/indicators/indicator/p")

        Do While pNodes.MoveNext
            IndForm.curIndBox.Items.Add(pNodes.Current.Value)
        Loop `

Comment: No, the path I provided is looking for the ID in the `id` element, which is a child of the `outcome` element (is that not what you wanted? your comment is not clear).  Please try my slightly modified path above.  It seems your sample XML has the element `files` as the root while your sample code had `curriculum` at the beginning of the path. Which is correct?

Comment: files is correct. Fixed. Doesn't show error, just nothing gets populated to the listbox. Should i get rid of the  navigator.selectsinglenode and moveto statemenets too?

Comment: What about the `goal_section` part? That doesn't seem to be in the XML either. I've removed that from the path too.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I was trying to post a simple version of the XML document that was provided to me. I like to understand how the code work. Is this correct:
     `Dim pNodes as XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select("/files/outcomes/outcome[id = '" & id & "']/indicators/indicator/p")`

This works by selecting the node /files/outcomes/outcome/indicators/indicator/p that is part of the tree that has an ID element with the variable as its text. Is that right?

Comment: the iterator will move through the node. I noticed, though, that INNERTEXT isn't allowed with iterator. All the examples I see with loops write to console. Must be a way to write innertext to listbox though. If I can't get it to work, I could add an attribute to the indicators node that has the ID text. That would be easy to just select and loop though, writing to list box, but I would have to change about 50 files, each with 15 or more outcomes nodes.

Comment: I made a mistake with `.InnerText`. With `XPathNavigator`, it should be `.Value`. Are you saying that it's successfully iterating now?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but I will keep trying tonight. At work right now. I will keep trying tonight. I certainly appreciate the help

Comment: WORKING! You rock. By using the path you wrote, I didn't even need to iterate. I did the following:
       `Dim id As String
        id = Me.outListView.SelectedItems(0).Text
        Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument()
        doc.load("C:\Temp\" & sb & "_education_" & gr & ".XML")
        Dim idList As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/curriculum/outcomes/goal_section/outcome[identifier = '" & id & "']/indicators/indicator/p")
        For Each p As Xml.XmlNode In idList
            IndForm.curIndBox.Items.Add(p.InnerText)
        Next`

       Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Final working code, thanks JRRishe:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'get variable to identify node
    Dim id As String
    Dim out As String
    id = Me.outListView.SelectedItems(0).Text
    out = Me.outListView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    IndForm.SelOutBox.Text = id & "  " & out
    'start xpath navigation
    Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument()
    doc.load("C:\Temp\" & sb & "_education_" & gr & ".XML")

    'select the node with with variable, by text value
    Dim idList As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/curriculum/outcomes/outcome[id = '" & id & "']/indicators/indicator/p")
    For Each p As Xml.XmlNode In idList
        IndForm.curIndBox.Items.Add(p.InnerText)
    Next

    IndForm.Show()
End Sub
```